# array2d from bytestream without writing file to disk

Tags: c++, dlib

is it possible to initialise  `array2d` object in `dlib` from a byte stream?

The thing is that I receive bytestream which contains png file from external source and I do not want to create temp file and then read image from this file into array. Is it possible to skip write-to-file part?

Speaking the other way, is it possible to build array2d object from file kept in memory?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to make it - use OpenCV or some other external library that can read PNG file from memory:

```
size_t png_buffer_size = 1000;// example value
void* png_buffer; // your PNG image
cv::Mat buffer(1, png_buffer_size, CV_8UC1, png_buffer);
cv::Mat decoded = cv::imdecode(buffer, 1); // should be RGBA32 for PNG
dlib::cv_image<rgb_alpha_pixel> img(decoded); // this image can be used inside dlib
....
auto detections = detector(img);  // this image can be used to detect faces for example or inside any other algorithm
...
// if you need array2d - use assign_image
dlib::array2d<rgb_alpha_pixel> arr;
dlib::assign_image(arr, img);
```

Using dlib::cv_image is free in terms of performance - it does not make deep-copy of cv::Mat data, so you should make cv::Mat exists and not changed until cv_image is destroyed (it is keeping pointer inside)

if you need some small PNG reading library - you can try [lodepng](http://lodev.org/lodepng/)

And I think some future release of dlib can have this function inside

Comment: Hi @Evgeniy thanks for the reply. This answers my question even though I did not want to believe this is to be the case. Just a quick question: this lodepng library will not read png stream in a required array2d format, right?

Comment: array2d is a simple memory buffer with some additional functions. after constructing array2d you can get access to memory pointer with dlib::image_data(). And I cant answer about details for lodepng - I used it some years ago, but now I switched to static-linked opencv

Answer (score -3):

Googled array2d in dlib and found this helper function.

```
   template <
        typename T,
        typename mem_manager
        >
    void deserialize (
        array2d<T,mem_manager>& item, 
        std::istream& in
    );   
    /*!
        provides deserialization support 
    !*/
```

I am not sure what writing it to a file and then reading it back would get you.

Comment: deserialize can be used to load/save array2d to disk/memory, but it will not  ecode/decode PNG (or any other) format